# Livewire Livewire > encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the > [filter-simulators] component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I making a live wire component for filter products but I have a error on Livewire

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Area;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Simulator;

class FilterSimulators extends Component
{

    public $areas;
    public $simulators;

    public function mount(){
        $this->areas = Area::get();
        $this->simulators = Simulator::orderBy('name', 'desc')->get();
    }

    public function filterByArea($type)
    {
        $this->simulators = Simulator::orderBy('name', 'desc')->get();
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.filter-simulators');
    }
}
```

and the Livewire component

```
<div>
    <div class="has-text-centered">
        <ul class="list-filter-simulators">
            @foreach ($areas as $area)
                <li class="mx-15">
                    <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="filterByArea('{{ $area->slug }}')" class="text-sm">{{ $area->name }}</a>
                </li>    
            @endforeach
            
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="columns is-multiline mt-45">
        @foreach ($simulators as $simulator)
        <div class="column m-15 widget-simulator" style="background-image: url('/img/simulator01.webp')">
            <h4 class="text-white is-size-5 text-bold">{{ $simulator->name }}</h4>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

and when I press anchor filterByArea show a popup (I remove logic of filter Eloquent for simplify example)

> Livewire\Exceptions\CorruptComponentPayloadException Livewire
> encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the
> [filter-simulators] component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the
> Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests.

I search and try to convert $simulators to protecto and add to return view manually but I get the same error, maybe because this is my first day using Live Wire hahaha, and the beginning the component show my all data correctly only when I press a button launch the error, I hope someone can help me :)

Thanks! Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also encountered the same issue before. We can solve this issue by manually passing the collection when rendering the component. To have the filtering option, we can introduce a new variable to enable filtering.

Let's assume that we introduce a variable to store the filter value `$filter_area_type`

```php
class FilterSimulators extends Component
{

    public $areas;
    public $filter_area_type; 

    public function mount(){
        $this->areas = Area::get();
    }

    public function filterByArea($type)
    {
      $this->filter_by_area = $type;

    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        $simulators = Simulator::query()
                      ->when($this->filter_area_type, fn($q, $type) => $q->where('area',$type))
                      ->orderBy('name', 'desc')->get();

        return view('livewire.filter-simulators',[
           'simulators' => $simulators     
          ]);
    }
}
```

Note that i have used `when` which can allow us to conditionally append the where clause to the query.

If we want to reset the filters, we can introduce another function and reset only the `$filter_area_type` variable as below,

```php
    public function resetFilterArea(){
        $this->reset('filter_area_type');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but I get the same error message, I using npm run watch always so use :3000 but I try to test without:3000 of browsersync and this work fine, but not with :3000 hahaha I dont know why

Comment: @DiegoCortés please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue as mentioned in the OP.